# How to use xbindkeys to switch workspaces in Gnome overview?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell, xbindkeys

Here is my `~/.xbindkeysrc` config:

```
"gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'imports.ui.main.wm._showWorkspaceSwitcher(global.display, null, { get_name() { return `switch-to-workspace-down` } });'"
   b:8

"gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'imports.ui.main.wm._showWorkspaceSwitcher(global.display, null, { get_name() { return `switch-to-workspace-up` } });'"
   b:9
```

It assigns workspace switching to my mouse buttons. And it works everywhere but in Gnome overview (when you press the Super key you can see this overview). Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

I can patch `gnome-shell` if it's needed. But I don't what should be in the patch :)

**My environment**

- Gnome Shell 3.36.4
- Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by using `easystroke` package

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

Answer (score 2):

> it works everywhere but in Gnome overview (when you press the Super key you can see this overview). Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

Not with xbindkeys. Within Xorg, the overview relies on X11 global grabs to receive input (much like right-click popup menus) and as an unintended consequence this prevents other programs from receiving even the global hotkeys. If you patched this out, I suspect you would be unable to use the keyboard within the overview at all, not even to close it using Esc (as it cannot receive focus like a normal window).

In other words, only gnome-shell itself can receive input at that point, so you would need to write a gnome-shell extension to hook mouse buttons. (This wouldn't be a bad option actually -- it would avoid the indirection via D-Bus; you could literally just call _showWorkspaceSwitcher() from your extension's JS code.)

Alternatively, you might have more luck with [interception-tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools) which works by reading the low-level input events before they even reach Xorg.